# Grunt Connect Proxy: 404

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

i had a working grunt setup for months and without changing anything on my side, the proxy stuff stopped working. It might be related to some npm package updates or system updates (os x), but somehow my proxy broke:

I have the following proxy log, when doing a request:

> /web/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/token ->
>   http://gambify.sites.dev:80/web/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/token

And this results in a 404 not found.
However, if i curl my request directly to http://gambify.sites.dev:80/web/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/token everything seems to be working fine, so my endpoint is actually there. And grunt also realizes the request and proxies to that location, but I am still getting a 404.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Best Regards,
Marc

Comment: I fixed it by setting "host" header to my domain. Example http://stackoverflow.com/a/26742619/542501

Comment: I actually found out that it was related to my version of Connect Proxy, I am not entirely sure how to fix it, but changing versions did it for me. Maybe the Host is the issue for other people!